# How to test form.valueChanges in Angular?

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-reactive-forms

How to correctly unit test (Karma, Jasmine), that emmisions of `valueChanges` dispatches a `FormUpdated` action?

```ts
beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [...],
    providers: [
      { provide: Store, useValue: MOCK_STORE },
    ],
    declarations: [FormComponent],
    schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
  })
    .compileComponents();
}));

beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FormComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
});
```

```ts
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {
    searchForm: FormGroup;

    constructor(private readonly fb: FormBuilder, private readonly store: Store<AppState>) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.searchForm = this.fb.group({});
        this.searchForm.valueChanges.subscribe(value => this.store.dispatch(new FormUpdated(value)));
    }
}
```

I have tried something like this:

```ts
it('should dispatch action for valueChanges', () => {
    const spy = spyOn(component['store'], 'dispatch');
    spyOn(component.searchForm, 'valueChanges').and.returnValue(of({}));

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

But this does not work - the spy has not been called.

*[Edit1] - Based on comments and answer:*

The problem is with the test asynchronicity. Some part of `ngOnInit` calls `setTimeout(() => this.searchForm.get('field').updateValueAndValidity();)`) which causes an emmision to `this.searchForm.valueChanges()` so the `this.store.dispatch` **is actually called but after** the `expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)`.

I have tried to add `fakeAsync()`, `tick()` and `flushMicrotasks()` but with same outcome.

```ts
it('should dispatch action for valueChanges', () => {
    const spy = spyOn(component['store'], 'dispatch');
    spyOn(component.searchForm, 'valueChanges').and.returnValue(of({}));

    tick();
    flushMicrotasks();

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Comment: What is your beforeEach method ?

Comment: @bokzor `beforeEach` added

Comment: But where are you firing changes? Maybe add `component.searchForm.setValue({})` before `spyOn`?

Comment: @yurzui, bozkor: please see  *[Edit1]* to clarify my issue. And sorry that I missed to add such an important piece of information.

Comment: Maybe you can manually can the ngInit during the test.
it('should dispatch action for valueChanges', () => {
    component.ngOnInit();
}

Comment: `ngOnInit` is run (automatically) with the first `.detectChanges` which is located in `beforeEach()`

Comment: @Felix good to know...

Answer (score 6):

You want to test changes on a form without inputs.
Maybe try with this :

```
this.searchForm = this.fb.group({description: ['your_input']});
```

.

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [...],
    providers: [
      { provide: Store, useValue: MOCK_STORE },
    ],
    declarations: [FormComponent],
    schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
  })
    .compileComponents();
}));

beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FormComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
});

it('should dispatch action for valueChanges', () => {
    const spy = spyOn(TestBed.get(Store<AppState>), 'dispatch') 
    component.searchForm.controls['your_input'].setValue('test') // This will trigger change
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Comment: `component.searchForm.controls['your_input'].setValue('test')`
this has successfully triggered the valueChange. Thank you!